# Email Forwarding Google specific Emails ONLY

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I used Gmail's Auto Forwarding to forward an email from mine to another.  I only want to Forward specific emails so I tried the to use the filter.

I created a filter and added on the FROM field, including in it the only email address that I wanted to be forwarded.

The problem is, all emails, whether from the email address I filtered or not are still forwarded to the other email.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > Forwarding. Click "Disable Forwarding".

Your filter will still forward the specific emails.

Comment: this works. i don't know why disabling forwarding works. when you already disabled it.